# Finding Eigenvalues of given linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of the linear operator
$T:C^\infty(0, 1)\to C^\infty(0, 1)$

$T(f)(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{x}, x \in (0,1) $

Using the definition :

$TF = \lambda F \iff \frac{f'(x)}{x} = \lambda f(x) $

At this point, though, I'm stuck.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Just write the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: ... and solve a differential equation.

Comment: any constant function is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$ we will first show that $\lambda$ must be real.

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ means there is an $f \neq 0$ such that $\dfrac{f^\prime(x)}{x} = Tf(x) = \lambda f(x)$ since $f$ is not identically zero, there is an $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$ that is 
$\lambda =\dfrac{f^\prime(x_0)}{x_0f(x_0)}$ which is a real number.

now will solve for $f$ the equation $\dfrac{f^\prime(x)}{x} = \lambda f(x)$ separating the variables, we find $$\dfrac{df}{f} = \lambda x$$ on integrating gives you $$ f = e^{\lambda x^2/2}\text{ is an eigenfunction  corresponding to the eigenvalue } \lambda, \text{ where $\lambda$ is any real number.}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $f$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, then $f$ satisfies
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{x} = \lambda f(x)
$$
For which $\lambda$ does this have a non-zero solution $f\in C^\infty(0,1)$?

Comment: That is the question I do not have an answer for.

Comment: Do you know how to solve separable differential equations?

Comment: See [this page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx) if you don't.

Comment: For future reference, if you want more helpful answers, provide more context to your questions. See [how to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)